# semantic list in scheme

Tags: scheme, semantic-web, predicate

I am currently working on a implementing a standard semantic network and am beyond lost. 
I have a global assc list:

`(define *database* '())`

and am trying to populate the list with the standard form as

```
((hellipcopter (isa (air-vehicle))         
               (has-part (propeller door)))
               .
               . 
               .
```

From The statements

```
(has-part helicopter propeller)
(has-part helicopter door)
(isa helicopter air-vehicle)
```

Here is my attempt

```
    (define (process-relation rel)
       (set! *database* (cons (cons (cons (cadr rel) (car rel)) (caddr rel))*database*)))
```

which prints out in this terrible fashion

```
       ((helicopter . has-part) . propeller)
       ((propeller . has-part) . blade)
```

I am new to scheme as you can tell, so i have some questions.

1. Why does cons form the statement like it does? (x . y)
2. How would you add a multiple parts, for instance, to the same object?
3. What would be the steps to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

A list is a chain of cons. eg. if you evaluate `'(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))` you get `(1 2 3)` since while the reader reads both dotted form and list form, the printer prints list form where it can. eg. if the `cdr` is a pair or `()` it omits the `.` and one pair of parentheses. If the last element in the chain is not `()` it is not a proper list and would require the dot form even for print. eg. `'(1 . (2 . 3))` is `(1 2 . 3)`.

`(list 1 2 3)` is the same as `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))`

To fix you code some places you use `cons` you shoud use `list` or add more `cons` so that the values are only in the `car` position.

Comment: That makes sense. I was unaware that list itself acted like that. My last question would be how would i add the tier to the alist. So like helicopter isnt listed twice for haspart and isa

Comment: @Ayleids You should perhaps make a procedure that takes one instance and one statement and return the new one. eg. `(augment-entry '(helicopter) '(has-part helicopter propeller)) ; ==> (helicopter (has-part propeller))`. You main procedure take a list of instances (database) and return a new database. `(update-db '() '(has-part helicopter propeller) ; ==> ((helicopter (has-part propeller))`. Good luck

Comment: I am confused what you mean by augment-entry?

Comment: @Ayleids It's shown an example. I can give another `(augment-entry '(helicopter (has-part propeller)) '(isa helicopter air-vehicle)) ; ==> (helicopter (isa (air-vehicle)) (has-part propeller))`. It adds the term to the structure.